# How does we calculate PSD of a dataset in R

Tags: r, spectral-density

I have a dataset of EEG signals over a period of time and I need to calculate PSD observation of it.

In matlab I can calculate the PSD of a signal, for that I have a built in function.

Does R have a function to calculate the PSD observation of a dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for `r power spectral density` lead me to [the spectrum function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/spectrum.html).